# How to Extract sub-string after delimiter but ignore if found between two tags?

Tags: delphi, lazarus

I need to extract a sub-string after a specific delimiter, but if the specified delimiter is between two other tags it should be ignored.

For example, take this test string:

> The quick <"@brown fox"> jumps over the lazy dog. The quick @*brown fox
>   jumps over the lazy dog*

The desired output would be:

> *brown fox jumps over the lazy dog*

This is because the first found @ delimiter is between two " " and so should be ignored, the second @ delimiter is not inside " " and so the text afterwards should be extracted.

I am able to find the starting position of the @ delimiter by using `Pos` and extracting the text to the right of it as shown below:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  S: string;
  I: Integer;
begin
  S := 'The quick <"@brown fox"> jumps over the lazy dog. The quick @brown fox jumps over the lazy dog';
  I := Pos('@', S);
  if I > 0 then
  begin
    ShowMessage(Copy(S, I, Length(S)));
  end;
end;
```

However this will always find the first @ delimiter regardless if it is surrounded by two " " or not. The result from the above is:

> @brown fox"> jumps over the lazy dog. The quick @*brown fox jumps over
>   the lazy dog*

where the desired result should be:

> *brown fox jumps over the lazy dog*

How can I change the code to ignore @ delimiters when using `Pos` if the delimiter is between two " " tags? I only want to find the first @ delimiter and copy the text afterwards.

It also does not matter if there are any other @ delimiters after the first valid one is found, for example this should also be valid:

> The quick <"@brown fox"> jumps over the lazy dog. The quick @*brown fox
>   jumps@ ov@er the lazy@ dog*

Should still return:

> *brown fox jumps over the lazy dog*

Because we are only interested in the first valid @ delimiter, ignoring anything else afterwards and ignoring anything between two " " tags.

Please note although I have tagged Delphi I do primarily use Lazarus so ideally I would need help coming up with a solution that does not use magic help with string helpers etc.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find out if the `@` is not within `"` enclosing tags, parse the string from the beginning.

If a delimiter is found after an opening tag, but there is no closing tag, this routine will extract the result as well.

```
function ExtractString(const s: String): String;
var
  tagOpen: Boolean;
  delimiterPos,i,j: Integer;
begin
  tagOpen := false;
  delimiterPos := 0;
  Result := '';
  for i := 1 to Length(s) do begin
    if (s[i] = '"') then begin
      tagOpen := not tagOpen;
      delimiterPos := 0;
    end
    else begin
      if (s[i] = '@') then begin
        if (delimiterPos = 0) then
          delimiterPos := i;
        if not tagOpen then // Found answer
          Break;
      end;
    end;         
  end;

  // If there is no closing tag and a delimiter is found
  // since the last opening tag, deliver a result. 
  if (delimiterPos > 0) then begin
    // Finally extract the string and remove all `@` delimiters.
    SetLength(Result,Length(s)-delimiterPos);
    j := 0;
    for i := 1 to Length(Result) do begin
      Inc(delimiterPos);
      if (s[delimiterPos] <> '@') then begin
        Inc(j);
        Result[j] := s[delimiterPos];
      end;
    end;
    SetLength(Result,j);      
  end;
end;
```

Comment: brilliant, and thanks for adding in the comments too :)

Answer (score 0):

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  S: string;
  L, I: Integer;
  take : Boolean;
begin
  S := 'The quick <"@brown fox"> jumps over the lazy dog. The quick @brown fox jumps over the lazy dog';
  L := Length(S);
  I := Pos('@', S);

  while I > 0 do
  begin
    take := True;
    if I > 1 then take := S[I-1] <> '"';
    if take then begin
      if I < L then
        ShowMessage(Copy(S, I + 1, L));
      Break;
    end;
    S[I] := '_';
    I := Pos('@', S);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Does not work if the `"` opening tag is more than one position before `@`, or is the closing tag.